# Telegram bot send only to 1 user

Tags: java, https, telegram, telegram-bot

I created chat bot and wrote a simple java application to send https request to

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot(botcredentials)/sendMessage?chat_id={chatid}&text="+telegramMessage
```

and it works for my telegram account, I tried to connect some more users to this bot and they can't see any updates (I mean I receive message for myself, but no one else could see them).

Perhaps I should make my bot ?public? 
Or every user has its own chat_id with my bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every chat with your bot has its own id. You can get the chat id of your bot with another user as soon as someone interacts with your bot through the [Update object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) received either through [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method or a [Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

Comment: Brillian. Thanks. That is what I can't find. So, as I understand. After using getUpdates I got an JSON, from which I could extract all persons, who subscribe on my bot. And after it I could send a message to all of them

Comment: Exactly. When calling the getUpdate you get an Array of Update objects as JSON, which contains the chat id of all users that interacted with your since your previous getUpdate call.

Comment: @Shiffty Can i send message on user's telegram from my website? When user subscribe on my site.